# Как отправить ARP запрос?

Tags: golang

Как отправить самый простой `ARP` запрос на сервер через `Ethernet` канал при помощи `Golang`? В документации про `ARP` ничего не нашел. Как быть?

Comment: https://github.com/mdlayher/arp не смотрели?

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan я то видел, только вот документации нету.

Comment: там ссылка на [godoc](https://godoc.org/github.com/mdlayher/arp) внизу

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan трудная документация)